# How to Pop a Modal Page Passing it's data to a Main Page?

Tags: c#, data-binding, xamarin.forms

I get some information on a Modal and try to pass it to the main page, but PopModalAsync returns an exception for me

```
//Here I get the information typed by the user through a button,
//And I need to pass it to my Main Page.
//It never works when the attributions aren't commented
private async void novoProd_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var el = (Produto)PickerProduto.SelectedItem;

    produto.Nome    = Convert.ToString(Name.Text);
    produto.Volume  = double.Parse(Volume.Text);
    produto.Preco   = double.Parse(Preco.Text);
    produto.Taxa    = double.Parse(Taxa.Text);
    produto.Uso     = el.UsoIndex;

    await Navigation.PopModalAsync();
}
```

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: "System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."